# Is there a way to follow and be notified when a question is removed from 'hold' status?

Tags: feature-request

So I can access and answer that particular question instead of searching for it again in the "unanswered' tab.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it by favoriting a question.

There is a star icon below the down arrow button on the left side of each question. You can see it here as well. Just click it and this question will be added into your favorite question list.

Now, whenever that favorited question is modified (edited, answered, or reopened etc), you will see a count on [favorites tab](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/17519/j-a?tab=favorites) on your profile page. Like this,

[image]

When you open this tab, you will see highlighted question(s) which were updated since you last visited this tab.

You can unfavorite that question anytime by clicking that star icon again.

You can search your favorite questions by typing `infavorites:mine` in the search bar.

More information about Favorite Questions can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/321725).

Comment: gonna give that a try, and will accept your answer if it works as advertised, thank you A J